# list rows with a string primary key sqlite in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a table

```
char const *createsql_lp      =  "CREATE TABLE license_plate("
                          "name              VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,"
                          "permanence           BOOLEAN,"
                          "begin_time           INTEGER,"
                          "end_time             INTEGER,"
                          "description   VARCHAR(128));";
```

the name of the license plate is the primary key.
and  the result is like this:

```
name    permanence      begin_time      end_time        description
QQ-5566 0       1111    2222    QQ
ABCD-12 1       24336   99997   AA
ABC-1234        1       24335   99996   BB
RD-610  0       333     444     CC
```

how can I dump all the columns of "ABC-1234" and "RD-610"?

I was modified a code but the table have row_id
so that he uses `SELECT * FROM license_plate LIMIT ?2 OFFSET ?3;`

but I can't use `OFFSET` ABC-1234

```
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM license_plate LIMIT ?1 OFFSET ?2;";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);
    if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("db not open\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, number); 
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, from_index, strlen(from_index), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);    
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        LicensePlate license_plate;
        license_plate.name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
        license_plate.permanence = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2);
        license_plate.begin_time = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 3);
        license_plate.end_time = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 4);
        license_plate.description = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5)); 
        license_plate_list.push_back(license_plate);
    }

    // sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    ret = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

it shows  "not an error" and the the errmsg of the `sqlite3_finalize()` is  datatype mismatch

Comment: Don't tag a C++ question with C — you'll annoy those who might otherwise try to help you.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to modify the query string?

Comment: @kiranBiradar I don't  under what you mean.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM license_plate WHERE NAME=\"ABC-1234\" OR NAME=\"RD-610\";"` will do the job right?

Comment: I only have ABC-1234 but I'd like to dump all or just the number I want of  the rows after it.

Comment: @supportHK: tables are not ordered, you need an explicit sort if you want order

Comment: @Mat I just want the order how it was created so that I can't  ORDER BY any columns.I tried select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER but I can't use any ORDER.

Comment: Again, there is no such order. Tables are bags of rows, not ordered lists of rows. You can't rely on insertion order. (It will work in toy examples, but it will break in real life scenarios, usually at the worts possible time - and it is extremely hard to fix.) If you need order, add an ordering key (autoincrement column for example).

Comment: I see. I just thought there is another way to get the rows number like
sqlite3_get_table().but if I want to ORDER by name, how to write the sql?

Comment: I tried "SELECT * FROM license_plate LIMIT 2,2;" works but the problem is that I can't know the row number from primary key.

Comment: Again, you need to introduce an explicit sort. One way is to add an auto-incrementing primary key which will reflect the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1 how can I dump all the columns of "ABC-1234" and "RD-610"?

```
SELECT * FROM license_plate WHERE name = 'ABC-1234' OR name = 'RD-610';
```

[image]

> I only have ABC-1234 but I'd like to dump all or just the number I want of the rows after it.

This would work BUT not necessarilly after a vacumn, as the rowid could be renumbered.

```
SELECT *,rowid FROM license_plate WHERE rowid >= (SELECT rowid FROM license_plate WHERE name = 'ABC-1234') LIMIT 2;
```

[image]

- rowid is a normally hidden column that exists for ALL table except those defined using WITHOUT ROWID. As you can see this has been included in the output to demonstarte it's existence and value.
- `LIMIT 9223372036854775807` would guarantee all rows, as would not including the LIMIT clause, additionally as would `LIMIT (SELECT count() FROM license_plate)`.

If the table were created with an alias of the rowid, then hte issue of renumbering is after a vacumn is prevented. e.g. if the table were create as per :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS license_plate; /*<<<<< DROPPED FOR DEMO */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS license_plate(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, /*<<<<< ROWID ALIAS */
  name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE, /* <<<<< UNIQUE constraint for name */
  permanence BOOLEAN,
  begin_time INTEGER,
  end_time INTEGER,
  description VARCHAR(128)
);
```

- Note there is no signifacnt overhead in add the alias.

And the following rows were added (more rows to demonstrate limited selection)

```
INSERT INTO license_plate (name,permanence,begin_time,end_time,description) VALUES
    ('QQ-5566',0,1111,2222,'QQ'),
    ('ABCD-12',1,24336,99997,'AA'),
    ('ABC-1234',1,24335,99996,'BB'),
    ('RD-610',0,333,444,'CC'),
    ('AD-610',0,333,444,'DD'),
    ('BD-610',0,333,444,'EE'),
    ('CD-610',0,333,444,'FF')
;
```

Then the **id** column will be in order.

As such

```
SELECT * FROM license_plate 
    WHERE id /* or rowid both the same */ >= (SELECT rowid /* or id */ FROM license_plate WHERE name = 'ABC-1234') LIMIT 2
;
```

- is virtually guaranteed to order in insert order as long as the **id** column hasn't been manipultated and that more then 9223372036854775807 rows haven't been inserted.
- deleting a row will result in a gap in the sequence, so you should never assume a monotonically increasing value for the id.

[image]

The following will select all plates between the first ('ABC-1234') and last('AD-610') given plates according to the insert order :-

```
SELECT * FROM license_plate 
WHERE id /* or rowid both the same */ >= (SELECT rowid /* or id */ FROM license_plate WHERE name = 'ABC-1234')
AND id <= (SELECT id FROM license_plate WHERE name = 'AD-610')
;
```

[image]

You could add the AUTOINCREMENT keyword, this ensures that only a higher number is used. It only normally comes into play after a rowid value of 9223372036854775807 has been reached and then instead of inserting a row an SQLITE_FULL error is raised.

You may wish to refer to 
[SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). This covers both rowid, aliases of rowid and AUTOINCREMENT (which can only be used for an  alias of the rowid).